# Code generation in Golang: using the go/ast package to add doc comments,but comments‘ site not right

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

When I execute go generate in the errrmsg directory, the comments for the function are not in the correct location

```
// Code generated by gen_code. DO NOT EDIT.
// 提示内容："成功"
// 状态码：10000
// 提示内容："失败"
// 状态码：10001
package errmsg

const (
    TypeCodeSuccess = 10000
    TypeCodeFailed  = 10001
)

func GetSuccess() Resp {
    return Resp{Code: TypeCodeSuccess, Msg: TypeMsgSuccess}
}

func GetFailed() Resp {
    return Resp{Code: TypeCodeFailed, Msg: TypeMsgFailed}
}
```

This is my code address.
[https://github.com/KingPuiWong/generrcode/blob/master/gencode/main.go](https://stackoverflow.com)

When I try like this, but it still doesn't work, do you know how to solve it? Thank you.

```
    commentMap := ast.NewCommentMap(fset, file, file.Comments)
    ast.Inspect(file, func(node ast.Node) bool {
        switch x := node.(type) {
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            if strings.HasPrefix(x.Name.Name, "Get") {
                commentText := x.Doc.List[0].Text
                fmt.Println()
                fmt.Printf("comment:%s", commentText)
                commentMap[x] = []*ast.CommentGroup{{List: []*ast.Comment{{Text: commentText, Slash: token.Pos(int(x.Pos() - 1))}}}}
            }
        }
        return true
    })

    ast.Print(fset, file)
    //os.Exit(1)
    // 保存已分配的错误码
    err = saveLastErrorCode(projectName, lastCode)
    if err != nil {
        return err
```

Here's what I want to generate.

```
// Code generated by gen_code. DO NOT EDIT.
package errmsg

const (
    TypeCodeSuccess = 10000
    TypeCodeFailed  = 10001
)

// 提示内容："成功"
// 状态码：10000
func GetSuccess() Resp {
    return Resp{Code: TypeCodeSuccess, Msg: TypeMsgSuccess}
}


// 提示内容："失败"
// 状态码：10001
func GetFailed() Resp {
    return Resp{Code: TypeCodeFailed, Msg: TypeMsgFailed}
}
```